# How to Automate Import File from Specific Folder into Toad for Oracle using Python?

Tags: python, oracle, importdata

I manage to automate download periodically to a specific folder called "datafolder" and now I try to automate import the newest file in "datafolder" into Toad for Oracle. I used:

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:\Users\USER\Desktop\belajar\ProjectDAS\downloaded_files\*csv')
newest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime, default=None)

To get the newest file and I already make the table in oracle, but still can't automate the importation periodically. The newest file contains the data of the beginning period to the latest

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For the load into Oracle Database in Python, see [Loading CSV Files into Oracle Database](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database).  I'd recommend writing a program for this, and then use some external tool to invoke it periodically.  For example on Linux, you would set up a crontab entry.  Once the data is in the Database, you will be be able to access it from Toad.